# The difference between "jest"and "joke"

Tags: difference, word-difference

Can the words "**[joke](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/joke)**" and "**[jest](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jest?q=JEST)**" be interchangeable in the following context?

For example, sometimes when people say a **joke** (=jest), they later denote that "it's just a **joke**" so they can say "It's just a **jest**"?

Comment: Why is this question downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Jests** and **jokes** are frequently interchangeable when they refer to language - what people have said or written rather than to actions. (Note that it's idiomatic to **tell a joke** or **play a joke on** and to **speak in jest**.)

Jests are also described as playful banter, droll tales - although their meaning has evolved over time.

They once signified an act intended to amuse and could also refer to a person being ridiculed; these senses of the word are archaic.

From jest we get **a jester**, a figure both of fun and subtle influence, whose role was to entertain the court and is an important figure in some historic plays.

Unlike **jest** today, the word **joke** can be used in other contexts.

You can play a joke on someone, a prank (whereby you surprise and hopefully amuse them)

and you can call someone a joke, meaning that they are worthless, incompetent to hold office or do a job.

In the context you refer to, the words mean the same thing.

https://wikidiff.com/joke/jest
https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/jest

Comment: So it's idiomatic to say "It's just a jest!"?

Comment: When you are referring to something that someone said jokingly, yes.